# How to get current url route pattern in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Lets imagine, I have a route defined like the following:

```
constraints MyRouteConstraint.new do
  get ':param/:param1/:param2', to: 'controller#action'
end
```

How can I get the pattern ':param/:param1/:param2' in my controller?
I know there is Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/param/param1/param2" but it raises an error 'No Route matches'

update:

```
Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(request) do |route, matches, parameters|
  return route.path.spec.to_s if route.path.required_names.all? { |p| request.params.keys.include? p }
end.flatten.compact.first
```

Answer (score 1):

Since rails 7.1 there is `request.route_uri_pattern`

See
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-route_uri_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is what you're looking for, this is meant to be used in your views.

You can try `request.fullpath`

Returns the String full path including params of the last URL requested.

```
# get "/articles"
request.fullpath # => "/articles"

# get "/articles?page=2"
request.fullpath # => "/articles?page=2"
```

See docs here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url

Comment: no, i would like to get ':param/:param1/:param2' exactly.
see update

Comment: Ever figure this out?